# Deadly, Heavier than Air Gas

Tags: science-based, gas

In a given fantasy world, I need a deadly (yet not magical) gas that will naturally pool in low depressions and valleys.

The level of magic is not high, so I'd like it to be an actual chemical that an astute reader/player might be able to identify.

Ideally, it should be mostly opaque in large quantities and deadly to any unprotected living creature.

Does such a substance exist? Can it?

Comment: There's hexafluoride gas, but it's transparent and would [sound hilarious](https://youtu.be/Kvr9LFzOo50) to die in... Alternatively there's carbon monoxide. How resistant to wind should it be?

Comment: How immediate should the deadly effect be? If all the normal air is replaced by an inert, heavier-than-air gas, people die shortly after they can no longer hold their breath.

Comment: @Frostfyre That would also work, the average dark ages man would likely not be able to tell the difference. I would prefer a good opaque and evil looking substance in that case, though.

Comment: @DannyReagan It seems more evil to be invisible; insidious. I think the only reason media makes evil gas visible is so the audience has something to visualize. Also, I know a mexican place that indirectly serves evil gas. It's invisible.

Comment: @Samuel I'm leaning towards Chlorine at the moment, because it is a nice sickly yellow; deadly, but not instantly lethal; and can plausibly be naturally occurring.

Comment: An advantage to inert gases is that humans would probably not know that they were suffocating until it is too late. The desire to breath is driven by CO2 build up. Humans readily pass out (and die) in oxygen-starved environments without having the faintest idea that anything is wrong until the last minute.

Comment: The process used to make heavy water -- used in some nuclear power plants -- out of regular water involves large quantities of hydrogen sulfide gas, which as some of the answers note, meets many of your criteria. The gas escaping and pooling in populated areas is a serious safety concern for heavy water production plants. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girdler_sulfide_process for details. (My family lives near the Bruce plant mentioned in the article, though it is no longer in the heavy water production business.)

Comment: Must it be a vapor or is a mist acceptable?  If mists are OK, then you can introduce all sorts of nasty stuff in microscopic droplet form.

Comment: Any LPG works, I think. You can choose between suffocation and explosion. "One volume of liquid butane or propane produces approximately 250 volumes of gas and thus a leak of liquid is a grave hazard, especially on a boat. **Since LPG vapour is denser than air, leaked LPG vapour will fall and flow along cockpit floors, bilges, etc and the vapour may travel some distance**."  http://www.boatsafetyscheme.org/about-us/ecp-review-2012/ecp-review-2012-pt7/

Comment: You are all proposing the oposite of what he wants. He wants a cloud of gas that is VISIBLE. LPG, Argon, CO2 are all invisible.

Comment: I'd argue that a deadly gas that *isn't* heavier than air would be pretty much useless to anyone outside a contained environment -- eventually, all of it would migrate to the upper bounds of the atmosphere and at worst kill the occasional overconfident bird.

Comment: **All** heavier-than-air gasses are deadly by oxygen deprivation.  If it's heavy enough not to simply mix into the air then the oxygen won't mix into it, either.

Answer (score 61):

During WW1 chemical warfare was used to break the deadlock at the ocidental front, with cruel consequences but little to no true military value. The simplest gas used was Chlorine, that accumulated in pools and was quite deadly (and quite horrible as a weapon). I believe this one or any of the other gases used in WW1 might work as you want. Phosgene is a alternative but does not produce the thick, greenish cloud that chlorine generates. Below is a chlorine release, photo is B&W, but the cloud color is greenish (green + white).

[image: Chlorine gas use]

Comment: Upvoting the use of chlorine gas feels wrong, but it is certainly more opaque than hexafluoride or carbon monoxide. Good choice.

Comment: upvoting because OP explicitly asked for an opaque gas

Comment: Americans might be more familiar with the name Mustard Gas for Chlorine gas, named such because of its mustard color.

Comment: @fredsbend [Chlorine gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine#World_War_I) and [mustard gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_mustard) are not the same thing.  See also [Chemical weapons in World War I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_weapons_in_World_War_I) - *"The Germans marked their shells yellow for mustard gas and green for chlorine and phosgene.."*

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that. Thank you.

Comment: Chlorine is toxic because as soon as it gets water, it turns into a powerfull acid (HCl). Its a asphixiating agent via destruction of pulmonary tract.

Answer (score 28):

Ok, I misunderstood the question, you want nasty, *seeable* stuff. The natural part is a bit problematic.
Here we go:

- **Nitrogen dioxide**
  Brownish stuff which is caused by burning which is a major air pollutant and has this sharp, biting odor. Poisonous, of course . To be exact, the atmospheric nitrogen is bonding with oxgen, first causing nitrogen monoxide which reduces himself to nitrogen dioxide. It reacts with water to nitric acid (exactly, that bad stuff) and nitric acid forms again cloud of nitrogen dioxide. Problem is, natural occurence is quite out of the line...you need too many of this stuff to form pools of nitric acid. So old mining industry or waste disposal are possible settings.
- **Chlorine**
  Has already been mentioned, but here is also the problem how it is generated. The best bet is salt (NaCl) which is reduced by acid to form chlorine.
- **Acid clouds**
  The most common acids like sulphuric acid and hydrochloric acid are creating fumes which are aerosols of small droplets like fog. They are not so much deadly because I cannot imagine that someone will try to enter this
  stuff, it is definitely a barrier.

For history here the old given invisible stuff:

- **Carbon dioxide**
  Yes, the thing used in soft drinks is also naturally occuring, but poisonous in higher concentrations. It is one feared component building up in silos or wine cellars and killing more people than all other gases. There is no protection (gas masks do not work: you need an oxygen supply). At one time 1700 people were killed by the [Nyos Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Nyos).
- **Hydrogen sulfide**
  While transparent, it cannot be ignored because it smells like rotten eggs (That is in fact the reason because rotten eggs produce hydrogen sulfide).
  It is not only very poisonous, but also flammable and explosive. It is created naturally in swamps and sewers.
- **Sulfur dioxide**
  Is created when burning sulfur which can be found in nature as native element. It is colorless, very toxic, but smells like a currently lighted
  match.
- **Ethane**
  Is besides methane the component of natural gas. While methane is lighter than air, ethane is heavier, colorless, odorless and poisonous in higher concentrations.

Comment: Strictly speaking, CO2 itself is not poisonous.  Instead, it displaces the oxygen in the air, causing death by suffocation.  Same is true for inert gasses like argon.

Comment: @jamesqf Suffocation from CO2 is actually distinct from [inert gas asphyxiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inert_gas_asphyxiation#Process) - you probably won't notice the inert gas until it's too late, while CO2 will make you [feel breathless](http://www.upc-online.org/nr/33005co2.htm) and like you're struggling to breathe - the natural reaction is to breathe faster. Your involuntary breathing rate is actually [controlled by CO2 levels in your blood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathing#Interaction).

Comment: Might want to add the $CO_2$ is also colorless, odorless, and tasteless.  One of its dangers is that someone not educated in its dangers, won't realize it's killing them.

Comment: Hydrogen sulfide is also common around volcanic vents.  There's a set of hot springs not too far from me that reek of the stuff (and that people can die in on bad days).

Comment: @Bob The opposite of inert gas asphyxiation: the med students at my old college had some class covering this where they breathed a mix of air with extra CO2 and extra oxygen. The mix was such that you could survive fine on it but because of the elevated CO2 you constantly felt like you were suffocating to death.

Comment: @Murphy I've always wanted to try that experiment!

Comment: @jamesqf, CO2 is poisonous. The toxicology appears to work primarily by acidifying your blood. Here's (a good resource)[http://www.blm.gov/style/medialib/blm/wy/information/NEPA/cfodocs/howell.Par.2800.File.dat/25apxC.pdf]. BTW, I am a volcanologist and work in caves with CO2 up to 3%. I'd like to see a reference that gives some scientific basis for the experiment Murphy reports.

Comment: If i remember correctly ethane and similar hydrocarbons will break down eventually in sunlight

Comment: Carbon dioxide, hydrogen sulphide and ethane are all colourless so do not meet the criteria of the question.

Comment: @foobarbecue Your own link: *> In addition, the lungs attempt to compensate by removing the excess CO2, which is the reason rapid breathing is apparent during acute CO2 exposure.* [*> partial pressure of carbon dioxide in the blood. Critical in regulating breathing levels and maintaining body pH*](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/PaCO2) [*> Respiratory minute volume increased to twice the resting ventilation on air at the end of the 15-h exposure to rising CO2 concentrations reaching 3% CO2*](http://www.dtic.mil/get-tr-doc/pdf?AD=ADA075627&Location=U2&doc=GetTRDoc.pdf)

Comment: Part of what is so dangerous about Hydrogen Sulfide is that at the more lethal concentrations it actually CAN be ignored because it will deaden your sense of smell. You can smell hydrogen sulfide at quite low concentrations, long before it reaches lethal concentrations.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff Yes, exactly! In higher concentrations, like in buried  sewer containers, it can kill the nose so quickly, that the person going into the man hole does not even notice. And then, it gets cruel:  Sometimes, the helping person does not notice it either. And  - in real life - it happens that a third person dies helping. Dangerous indeed.

Answer (score 24):

Another possibility is Bromine. It's denser than air, so it will pool nicely, and has the literary advantage that it's *red*, with all the symbolism that entails. It's toxic at high concentration, but it also stinks, so it's hard to ignore and hard to imagine anyone getting killed inadvertently, as opposed to silent killers like CO<sub>2</sub>.

Comment: Like the idea and the effects, but Bromine is a liquid to about 50-60 C, no?  You'd have to be pretty warm to have this as a gas.

Comment: No, that's boiling point. You get visible gas evolved at room temperature. Just as  you get appreciable water vapor in the atmosphere, even though water boils at 100 C.

Comment: @Twelfth Water is a liquid to 100°C, yet water vapour exists in the atmosphere. Bromine vapour can likewise exist.  -edit- Ninjad!

Answer (score 15):

You actually have quite a few choices. Given your parameters,

- **Argon (Ar):** It’s a naturally occurring gas on Earth (it comes from the radioactive decay of a few other elements that naturally occur) and our senses can’t detect it (it’s tasteless, odorless, and invisible). It’s not really a poison in and of itself, but it replaces oxygen in low-lying areas and becomes an asphyxiation risk.
- **Chlorine (Cl):** This is a bit more noticeable: argon suffocates you while you breathe normally, while chlorine causes a much more painful reaction.  The gas becomes hydrochloric acid when it contacts water, and burns.  Inhaling it causes an instant crippling effect and probably gives you the most visually appalling death you can think of.  It does have a color and trace amounts of it become detectable.
- **Natural Gas (CH<sub>4</sub> & others):** This is actually completely scentless (the odor we recognize so well is added so we can ... well, recognize it so well).  Methane (CH<sub>4</sub>) in particular can work here, though combustion might be a hazard.  Inhaling it in large quantities for a short period of time cripples a human body and sets in motion a wide array of lung issues.  As much as anything, it replaces oxygen in the air (or outright consumes it) and reduces what our bodies can take in.
- **Hydrogen Sulfide (H<sub>2</sub>S):** This is an odd choice, but it gives you the colorless but horrible smell option.  This is the rotten egg scent many of us are aware of, though it should be noted that it deadens the senses and is harder to detect than you might think.  It would rather quickly discolor any copper the person might be carrying or using.  It doesn’t take much: 500 part per million will completely nuetralize the sense of smell and 800 ppm will cause death within 5 minutes (and an uncomfortable one at that).
- **Carbon Tetrachloride (CCl<sub>4</sub>):** This would be an interesting idea, though it’s a bit lighter and isn’t as likely to pool without a source.  It has a slightly sweet smell, but is otherwise pretty undetectable in a mediveal world.  It’s a horrible toxin to the liver, will place people into comas, goes after our central nervous system, and causes symptoms of depression.  The deadening of the nervous system can also dissociate yourself from your body.
- **Sulfur Hexafloride (SF<sub>6</sub>):**  This one could be fun: it’s odorless, colorless, and not very detectable until we get to sound.  It has the opposite effect to helium, lowering ones voice by several octaves (the give away that you are in it is that everyone’s voice goes lower).  It’s not really toxic in and of itself: most of the death risk is from displacing oxygen and not leaving enough behind for our uses.  It’s also a functioning anesthetic, just below nitrous oxide (laughing gas) in its effectiveness

There’s a pretty good array. You could probably be picky between severity and speed of reaction on the one side and color, scent, and taste on the other. If there were specific parameters that you were interested in, we could probably tailor the gas for you a bit better.  Everything listed above is decently commonplace on our globe and is explainable.

Answer (score 9):

My first thought is Carbon Dioxide.

It doesn't seem that deadly, but it is! (...assuming one breathes oxygen).

It has been known to pool into depressions and valleys (typically after a volcanic 'burp' or when deep water saturated with CO2 has been agitated by a distant earthquake or something).

Comment: CO2 is pretty light and will not pool into depressions easily.

Comment: http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lake_Nyos

Comment: Or, more generally, http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Limnic_eruption.

Comment: CO2 is also not opaque. You can't even smell it. This is not a good answer.

Answer (score 9):

NO2 or nitrogen dioxide is toxic, heavier than air and visible (opaque) in high concentrations as your question asked. It is reactive with organic materials (life) as it is an excellent oxidizing agent. Also forms a strong acid on reaction with water (nitric acid), and ozone on reaction with volatile organics in the presence of heat and light.

[Wikipedia on NO2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_dioxide)

[EPA on health effects of NO2](http://www.epa.gov/airquality/nitrogenoxides/health.html)

Answer (score 7):

Anhydrous ammonia, when subjected to moisture in air, forms a [ground-clinging cold fog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNkdAs1e7Cw) that rolls away from the point of dispersion and is quite noxious. It is also easier than almost anything else to make, and the final reaction after the fact tends to make the grass a little greener. Are there bonus points for being eco friendly?

Oh, and it's explosive.

Answer (score 4):

## [Radon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon)

Radon is a very heavy radioactive gas. It is naturally present in low concentrations almost everywhere in the world airs and in underground waters, but it is very hard to obtain in large quantities and will decay pretty quickly in a few days (isotope 222, the most long-lived, has a semi-life of a few less than 4 days), so you will need some way to replenish it. But, anyway, it surely do what you want:

- Tends to pool down on depressions and lower areas where it can't escape, like underground rooms, basements and mines. In fact, Radon is the heaviest naturally-occurring gas.
- In large quantities might suffocate creatures by displacing oxygen. Even if you can handle that, or if the concentration is not so high but still many times higher than natural level, its intense radioactivity will kill any unprotected living creature. If some creature survives the exposure, it still is very likely to die from cancer some time later.
- Even when <sup>222</sup>Rn decays to <sup>218</sup>Po in less than 4 days, then that also decays in a few more than 3 minutes to <sup>214</sup>Pb that decays in 27 minutes to <sup>214</sup>Bi, which decays in 20 minutes to <sup>214</sup>Po, which decays in some microseconds to <sup>210</sup>Pb which in 22 years became <sup>210</sup>Bi, which in five days become <sup>210</sup>Po, which in 138 days becomes the finally stable <sup>206</sup>Pb. The result is that your radon gas will quickly fill up with highly radioactive, heavy and toxic metallic dust. Further, that dust will tend to stick to surfaces and be dissolved in liquids, making it very hard to remove the radioactivity even if all the Radon gas is ventilated away.
- It would be almost invisible. Being a noble gas, Radon is tasteless and odorless. It is also colorless. However the mostly Lead (with a bit of Polunium and Bismuth) dust will not be, making it somewhat noticeable as a (likely gray, but not sure) smog. The smog will probably be very thin because Lead dust do not tend to be suspended in the air for long time and will soon accumulate in the ground. If there are some strong air currents in the place that do not disperse/leak the gas away, but do not allows the dust to settle down, then the smog will become quite noticeable.
- Even if the gas is invisible and the smog normally almost invisible (if you do not prevents the dust from setting down), an astute reader/player might still be able to identify it by the accumulating Lead-rich dust. Then, after identifying it, the player will die due to the radioactivity in a few minutes. You don't need to make the gas opaque and visible for it being noticeable, the accumulated/accumulating dust might be enough.
- Even most of digital machines, like smartphones and computers, are very likely to malfunction and glitch in such environment if not properly shielded from the radiaction.
- Unaware normal people will likely not understand what is horribly wrong with the place/places where the Radon is. For them, it will looks like some sort of terribly strong evil magical curse.

Comment: I have a background in nuclear power. You are breathing radon right now. I promise.

Comment: @SeanBoddy Yes, I know. It is responsible for most of the natural background radiation and is present in small concentrations in air (specially over continents except Antarctica, where almost everyone lives) and is also present in underground waters. In fact, I even possesses a bottle with monazitic Thorium-rich sand that I grabbed in a beach and there should be a higher than usual (but still safe) amount of Radon there.

Comment: As I understood the question, invisible gases are not wanted, but visible (opaque = intransparent) ones.

Answer (score 4):

There exist completely naturally occurring gases which satisfy the criteria. I remember that in the Transylvanian mountains there are locations where sanua-like buildings are built upon [such places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mofetta), where the gases have the following properties:

- heavier than air, doesn't mix with air.
- considered healthy to the bones, joints, etc., good against arthritis and similar illnesses.
- heavily toxic. One breath can easily kill you.

You can check the level of the gas with a cigarette lighter or a matchstick. If you lower the flame below the level of the gas, it goes out completely. The gas is completely invisible, and feels a little warm. If you carefully enter the "sauna" and sit down, you can be almost neck-deep in the gas, and completely safe.

[Tourist guide quote](http://transylvaniantravel.ro/en/prg/9/5/lake-st-ann-mohos), emphasis added:

> What is a mofette? Usually tourists don’t know the meaning but you
>   have to know that this is one of the many advantages that Sekler land
>   has. It’s a special bath without water. The gas is coming out of the
>   earth and as it gets into the blood-stream through the skin it starts
>   its healing process. These gases come up from the result of post
>   activity of the volcano and they are present in many places all over
>   Sekler land. The types of gases are **usually carbon dioxide and
>   sulphur**. It is good for circulation problems, blood-pressure problems
>   and for motorical problems. Of cause you need to have a few day
>   treatment if you want any results. The mofette can be very dangerous
>   too. Breathing in these gases can be fatal. We have to be careful, do
>   not bend under the gas sign line and do not mix up with sudden
>   movements.

Comment: What is the gas that you mention? (makes for an interesting addition to the setting that people use it but it is deadly)

Comment: I've added a tourist guide quote specifying the gases as "usually carbon dioxide and sulphur", but i couldn't find a source for the claimed danger (i.e. no mofette deaths).

Comment: @CeesTimmerman : There is little I could offer besides anectotal evidence, because these mofettes are not that well-known, and no one famous enough wrote about them in the English-speaking media. These are not tourist attractions with a large tourist industry built around them, they are just used by the local villagers and whoever happens to hear about them. It might be an exaggeration that "one breath can easily kill you" but i wouldn't risk my life to try it. I guess it can happen if you are alone, one breath could make you faint and then you die if no one is there to drag you out in time.

Comment: I've heard about suicides involving mofettes, I guess accidental deaths are uncommon because few people besides the locals know about them and they are very careful. Also, the gas is heavy, and doesn't mix with air, if you turn a cigarette lighter to maximum and lower it below the level, you can clearly see that only the "top part of the flame" burns. If you disturb the gas, you can see waves just as in water, of course, only with the help of lighters, because the gas is completely invisible.

Comment: The only safety mechanism (besides wooden rails to keep your from slipping and falling while sitting down or standing up) is that there is no door, and the door-frame is built in such a height that its bottom lies at neck level when you sit down inside, so any excess gases can flow out.

Answer (score 4):

***This is a real story about a lot of people dying.***

[Lake Nyos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Nyos) is in a volcanically active area of Cameroon. It sits over a pool of magma, which leaks carbon dioxide gas into the lake. The gas dissolves in the water, but the lake becomes supersaturated. That means that any sudden disturbance of the water (caused by a small earthquake or landslide, for example, which is not unlikely in a volcanic region), can cause it to suddenly release a *lot* of gas.

A massive cloud of carbon dioxide pouring down a hillside can kill a lot of people.

Wikipedia says,

> On August 21, 1986, a limnic eruption occurred at Lake Nyos which triggered the sudden release of about 100,000 - 300,000 tons (some other sources state as much as 1.6 million tons) of CO<sub>2</sub>; this cloud rose at nearly 100 kilometres per hour (62 mph). The gas spilled over the northern lip of the lake into a valley running roughly east-west from Cha to Subum, and then rushed down two valleys branching off it to the north, displacing all the air and suffocating some 1,700 people within 25 kilometres (16 mi) of the lake, mostly rural villagers, as well as 3,500 livestock. The worst affected villages were Cha, Nyos, and Subum. Scientists concluded from evidence that a 100 m (330 ft) fountain of water and foam formed at the surface of the lake. The huge amount of water rising suddenly caused much turbulence in the water, spawning a wave of at least 25 metres (82 ft) that would scour the shore of one side.
>
> Carbon dioxide, being about 1.5 times as dense as air, caused the cloud to “hug” the ground and descend down the valleys, where various villages were located. The mass was about 50 metres (160 ft) thick and it travelled downward at a rate of 20–50 kilometres per hour (12–31 mph). For roughly 23 kilometres (14 mi) the cloud remained condensed and dangerous, suffocating many of the people sleeping in Nyos, Kam, Cha, and Subum. About 4,000 inhabitants fled the area, and many of these developed respiratory problems, lesions, and paralysis as a result of the gases.

If you want coloured gas, you’ll need to use something other than carbon dioxide. However, do check whether the gas is water-soluble. If it is, a lake over a vent can cause a natural way for a lot of gas to gradually build up over a long time and then be suddenly, unpredictably released.

Comment: Nyos was my first thought when I read the question.  A possibly interesting side-note is considering this effect as the mechanism for the death of all the first-born during the original passover in the biblical book of Exodus.  The first-born slept in a place of honour on the ground floor.

Answer (score 3):

I think ozone might serve. It is roughly 50% heavier than air and is known to collect in basins like Los Angeles.

Most people will recognize the chemical by smell and they probably know that it is poisonous.

Ozone itself is a pale blue, however lethal concentrations are far far below what would be considered opaque. It would be visible in the form of smog when combining with organic molecules in the atmosphere. Sometimes smog can be rather opaque. If you had the right combination of organics naturally in your atmosphere, the smog could be the opaque component though it's the ozone that kills.

Answer (score 2):

Many welders have been killed by Argon Gas suffocation...As it pools in low areas especially in concrete foundations where it cannot escape...

EDT:
Argon is an inert shielding gas meaning when it is used for welding it shields the molten metal from exterior gases such as oxygen...It is used in Metal Inert Gas welding or MIG welding. It is odorless unless an odor is added such as garlic or onion fragrance. It is clear and it kills indiscriminately by starving the subject of oxygen death occurs relatively quickly usually under 3 min

Comment: could you expand this answer a little bit?  It's a good start.

Comment: Argon is an inert shielding gas meaning when it is used for welding it shields the molten metal from exterior gases such as oxygen...It is used in Metal Inert Gas welding or MIG welding. It is odorless unless an odor is added such as garlic or onion fragrance. It is clear and it kills indiscriminately by starving the subject of oxygen death occurs relatively quickly usually under 3 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Carbon Dioxide.

We have valleys with this on earth, they are called *Mazuku*, and have been responsible for deaths of humans, wildlife and lifestock both in recent history (e.g. Lake Nyos in the 1980s or smaller incidents like Mammoth Mountain, California in 2006) and in the more distant past (perhaps the reason that the Messel Pit in Germany has so many fossils is such an event happened there).

It's not visible though, but that could be solved by a visible effect being part of the world building.

If you really need to be able to see it, I'd go with high concentrations of chlorine, though note that it's likely to be poisonous in much lower concentrations than make it visible, so your characters can't just walk up to the smoky yellow-green clouds unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

My I ask why it has to be opaque? If it's so characters can recognize it, consider that seeing the gas is not the only way to recognize the existence of a deadly gas. Seeing the effects it has on others is a key way we do so in the real world.

I ask/say the above because the first thing that came to mind was Sarin. It is heavier than air as you request, it's quite deadly, and the effects on living things is recognizable to a learned observer. It is everything you seek except the opacity.

I would venture to say Sarin is a *better* killer due to its transparency; you don't know it's coming until you or someone close to you can't breathe anymore, at which point you're pretty much screwed.

If you're in the U.S., "60 Minutes" had a story on Sarin just two days ago. Go watch it.

Answer (score 0):

Nitrogen. It is deadly if it pools in a low place. Before you know it, you pass out and die. Nitrogen is odorless and colorless. It is used to flush explosive gasses from pressure vessels and other containers used in industry. Sometimes a worker will go into the container to perform repairs to the vessel. He gets lightheaded, faints, then dies very quickly. There are cases where others go in to save the worker, and they die, too.  The rule is, when you see a worker who is down and you don't know why, you don breathing gear.

Nitrogen is slightly lighter than air (which is itself 70% nitrogen) but I think it could be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to me that chlorine gas on lower elevations would lead to highly acidic rain rendering the higher elevations uninhabitable as well so you'd probably want something that doesn't combine with water with such enthusiasm.  Inert gases are probably the better option even though they have an annoying tendency to be transparent. And it doesn't really matter which inert gas it is since the effects and appearance would be all the same

Answer (score -1):

All gases mix completely with all other gases.  At least we haven't yet found a pair that act like oil and water.

So it will need to be regenerated somehow or it will diffuse away, especially if exposed to wind or other currents.

Comment: Hi Bloke Down The Pub, and welcome to Worldbuilding. Since especially the first half of this answer goes against several already posted answers, it would be beneficial if you can provide some kind of citation for your claim beyond "that's how I say it is". That is probably why this answer has been downvoted.